# Getting names of all kernel modules used by a particular module

Tags: linux-kernel

In the output of **lsmod** command, *Used by* column sometimes does not have the name of the kernel modules used by the module. For example, consider the following part-output of the **lsmod** command:

```
 Module                  Size  Used by
 xen_blkfront           16512  4 
 ext3                  137007  1 
 jbd                    54383  1 ext3
 mbcache                 7438  1 ext3
```

In the above output, **ext3** module is used by 1 module, but its name is not there. Similarly, **xen_blkfront** module is used by 4 modules, but there are no names for those modules. But, **jdb** and **mbcache** modules are used by **ext3** module. So, is there a way to get these missing module names ?

I need this because the kernel does not allow me to rmmod **ext3** module saying "ERROR: Module ext3 is in use".

Comment: Have you tried to umount any of filesystems that use ext3 - of course if it is possible (if it is not root fs)? Seems like kernel uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here I have mentioned ext3 just as an example of the module to state my point. I would like to know whether there is a way in general to know the module names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Used by" column shows not only the number of referencing modules, but the numer of times that *any* kernel code has taken a reference to the module.

For file systems and device drivers, this typically happens when a file/device is opened.

The source of those references is not tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, is there a way to remove such a module because as of now it is giving me error when I try to unload the module from the kernel using **rmmod** command.

Comment: Close those files/devices.

Comment: I closed the devices which were using the module and I was able to unload the module. Thanks CL for help.

Comment: Any idea what can make `iptable_*` modules being referenced? I was able to unload these modules a couple of times (the tables wasn't empty), but not right now. This time reference count is `1`, not `0` like before.

Comment: My bad, any rule or user-defined chain in a table result in 1 reference. That is, to unload iptables there must be no rules and no user-defined chains :( And here I thought I've found an easy way to reset iptables.